# Вопрос по циклам и спискам

Tags: python, python-3.x

Новичок в питоне, только изучаю.
Нужно написать функцию с двумя входными параметрами **(x,t)**,
где **x** - список целых чисел, **t** - целое число
Функция должна складывать попарно элементы списка **x[]** и сравнивать их сумму с **t**.
Если **x[i] + x[i + 1] == t**, то нужно удалить  второй элемент **x[i +1]** из списка и продолжить. В конце функция должна вывести финальный измененный список.  У меня получилось что-то вроде этого:

```
def trouble(x, t):
    i = 0
    while i < len(x):
        if x[i] + x[(i + 1)] != t:
            i += 1
        else:
            del x[i + 1]
    return x
```

Я получаю ошибку `index out of range`  на строчке с условием. Проблема в том, что в определенный момент при удалении элемента смещаются индексы, как я понимаю. Подскажите, как можно лучше решить эту проблемку? Пока не могу догнать.

Comment: `i < len(x) - 1:`

Comment: Благодарю)))) дольше пост писал))))

Answer (score 1):

`IndexError` происходит на последней итерации когда `i` является последним элементом списка. И при попытке обратиться к элементу под индексом `i + 1` мы выходим за границу списка. Поэтому цикл надо останавливать немного раньше

```
while i < len(x) - 1:
```

Comment: Спасибо большое за развернутый ответ))) буду знать теперь))))

Comment: @guilty4all если вам мой ответ помог то, пожалуйста, примите кго